# Running Autohotkey script inserted in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

How can I let the user insert their own Autohoykey script or javascript into a textbox in order to narrow a search query?

Comment: 1) You seem to have already asked basically the same question. 2) It is still too vague, be more specific! 3) What actual coding problem do you have? Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have a webapp that queries a database. Just saw someone who had a similar application but had a box to literally paste Autohotkey code into it that would either perform a query or refine it. I think that is not that vague....however no one seems to answer :(   i guess it would be something similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You could make an example. Since AHK is no query language, I find it hard to imagine how you would make a DB query with it. Where did you see it? Why don't you ask that person for code/help or at least a screenshot to post here?

Comment: [ADOSQL](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/83542-func-adosql-uses-ado-to-manage-sql-transactions-v503l/) is a function that allows you to do database queries.  I have used it in the past.